# I'm having some trouble with sending integer data with an intent. (android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to send integer data from one activity to another class by using intents but my integer data is just turning to zero by itself.

So I made this intent that sends the data about how many intervals the user wants to do to a class that creates viewgroups/viewholders depending on how many the user chose for a recycler view. The problem is that the int automatically turns into zero by itself which leads to the recycler list not being created. I've tried to make the list with a random number and it works, so nothing wrong with that part of the code.

Also after some debugging I narrowed down the problem to the getintent part of the because before I send the the data the number is correct but after I've sent it the number always turns into zero.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button decrementButton;
    TextView intervalCountTextView;
    Button incrementButton;
    int intervalCount = 0;
    Button intervalButtonSetter;
    private int numberOfIntervals = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        decrementButton = findViewById(R.id.decrementButton);
        intervalCountTextView = findViewById(R.id.intervallCount);
        incrementButton = findViewById(R.id.incrementButton);
        intervalButtonSetter = findViewById(R.id.intervalButtonSetter);

        decrementButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        decrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intervalCount--;
                intervalCountSetter();

            }
        });

        // make sure you can't decrement past zero

        incrementButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intervalCount++;
                intervalCountSetter();
            }
        });

        intervalButtonSetter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendDataToAdapter();
            }
        });
    }



    private void intervalCountSetter() {
        String intervalCountString = Integer.toString(intervalCount);
        intervalCountTextView.setText(intervalCountString);

        if (intervalCount > 0) {
            decrementButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            decrementButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void sendDataToAdapter() {
        String numberOfIntervalsString = intervalCountTextView.getText().toString();
        numberOfIntervals= Integer.parseInt(numberOfIntervalsString);
        setNumberOfIntervals(numberOfIntervals);
        if (numberOfIntervals > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sendDataToAdapter: We have the numbers");
            Log.d(TAG, "sendDataToAdapter: " + numberOfIntervals);
          startTimeActivity();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have to have at least 1 interval.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    private void startTimeActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, TimeActivity.class));
        Log.d(TAG, "startTimeActivity: TimeActivity has been started" + numberOfIntervals);


    }

    public int getNumberOfIntervals() {
        return numberOfIntervals;
    }

    public void setNumberOfIntervals(int numberOfIntervals) {
        this.numberOfIntervals = numberOfIntervals;
    }
}
```

```
public class TimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = TimeActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private MainActivity mainActivityObject = new MainActivity();
    private int numberOfIntervals = mainActivityObject.getNumberOfIntervals();
    private ArrayList<Integer> WTV = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> WET = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> RTV = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> RET = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_time);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started");



        Toast.makeText(this, "" + numberOfIntervals, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        //numberOfIntervals = intent.getIntExtra("Interval Count", 0);
        //Log.d(TAG, "" + numberOfIntervals);

        initializeViews();






    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initializeViews: Preparing views");
        //Make sure they can change through the R.strings


        WTV.add(R.string.work_text_view);
        WET.add(R.string.default_time_value);
        RTV.add(R.string.rest_text_view);
        RET.add(R.string.default_time_value);

        initializeRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initializeRecyclerView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "initializeRecyclerView: Initialize RecyclerView");
        RecyclerView intervalRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.intervalRecyclerView);
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, WTV, WET, RTV, RET);
        intervalRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        intervalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }
}
```

```
 private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";

    private ArrayList<Integer> mWorkTW = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mWorkET = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mRestTW = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mRestET = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;
    private MainActivity mainActivityObject = new MainActivity();
    private int numberOfIntervals = mainActivityObject.getNumberOfIntervals();








    public CustomAdapter( Context context , ArrayList<Integer> mWorkTW, ArrayList<Integer> mWorkET, ArrayList<Integer> mRestTW, ArrayList<Integer> mRestET) {

        this.mWorkTW = mWorkTW;
        this.mWorkET = mWorkET;
        this.mRestTW = mRestTW;
        this.mRestET = mRestET;
        this.mContext = context;
        Log.d(TAG, "CustomAdapter: " + numberOfIntervals);
    }





    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View customView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.time_row, viewGroup,false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(customView);
        return holder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called");
        viewHolder.workTextView.setText(R.string.work_text_view);
        viewHolder.restTextView.setText(R.string.rest_text_view);
        viewHolder.workEditText.setHint(R.string.default_time_value);
        viewHolder.restEditText.setHint(R.string.default_time_value);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d(TAG, "" + numberOfIntervals);
        return numberOfIntervals;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView workTextView;
        EditText workEditText;
        TextView restTextView;
        EditText restEditText;
        ConstraintLayout parentLayout;


        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            workTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.workTextView);
            workEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.workEditText);
            restTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restTextView);
            restEditText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restEditText);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);



        }
    }







}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/intervallCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.533" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/decrementButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/intervallCount"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/incrementButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/intervallCount"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/intervalButtonSetter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Set intervall"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/intervallCount" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TimeActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/intervalRecyclerView">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/workTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/work_text_view"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="31dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/workEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/default_time_value"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/rest_text_view"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/restEditText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.425"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/workEditText" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/restEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/default_time_value"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/workEditText" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I expect the int that is being sent from the activity to the class to be the sam and not change automatically to zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have one `Intent` as a local variable in `sendDataToAdapter()` which gets the number of intervals as extra. Since you don't do anything else with this `Intent`, it will be garbage collected once the method is finished, the extra will not be accessible from anywhere outside the method.

In `startTimeActivity()`, you instantiate a new `Intent` to start `TimeActivity`. This `Intent` does not have any extras. But this is the `Intent` whose extras will be passed on to `TimeActivity`.

So in order to put the number of intervals as extra to the correct `Intent`, you can add a parameter *numberOfIntervals* to `startTimeActivity()` 
(Please note I'm using a String constant to avoid errors caused by typos)

```
public static final String INTERVAL_COUNT = "INTERVAL_COUNT";

private void startTimeActivity(int numberOfIntervals) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(INTERVAL_COUNT, numberOfIntervals)
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "startTimeActivity: TimeActivity has been started" + numberOfIntervals);
}
```

Since you need to know the number of intervals in `CustomAdapter`, you can add another parameter to the constructor:

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> mWorkTW, ArrayList<Integer> mWorkET, ArrayList<Integer> mRestTW, ArrayList<Integer> mRestET, int numberOfIntervals) {
    this.mWorkTW = mWorkTW;
    // ...
    this.numberOfIntervals = numberOfIntervals;
    Log.d(TAG, "CustomAdapter: " + numberOfIntervals);
}
```

In `TimeActivity`, you can access the `int` value by calling `getIntent()`:

```
private int numberOfIntervals;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started");
    numberOfIntervals = getIntent().getIntExtra(INTERVAL_COUNT, 0);
    Toast.makeText(this, "" + numberOfIntervals, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "" + numberOfIntervals);
    initializeViews();
}
```

And finally, you can initialize the `RecyclerView` in `TimeActivity` as follows:

```
private void initializeRecyclerView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "initializeRecyclerView: Initialize RecyclerView");
    RecyclerView intervalRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.intervalRecyclerView);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, WTV, WET, RTV, RET, numberOfIntervals);
    intervalRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    intervalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer. Unfortunately your suggestion didn't work but there might be something to what you are saying, do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: @Nobeel Gardenish - I suppose there are other errors besides the one which I happened to find by reading your code. If you need help with finding them then please post a [MCVE] so I can use my IDE to reproduce your situation

Comment: Should it matter that when I write Intent intent = getIntent that it doesn't work?

Comment: @NobeelGardenish - yes, it should matter, since it indicates that there is something not working as expected. Would you like to add the missing files (some  layouts) to your question, so that I can run your app and debug it? Assuming the code you posted is the one which you are trying to fix. If it isn't, please update your code accordingly.

Comment: So I finally fixed the problem with the intent. Since my custom class doesn't extent the activity class my intent won't work. That's why I changed the code to a public getter and setter. Now I do still have the problem of when the data has reached the other class it still changes automatically to the value of zero. But then I tried to give it a hardcoded value so it did work. I can share the values between the classes.

Comment: Now the problem is the when I use the value that I get from the textview and try to send it to the other class it just changes to zero. But when I check my log the value is still correct inside of the Mainactivity class but zero in the custom class. I'll update my code and post the layout.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, you have to implement the recyclerview in the gradle app place. Here's the code   ```     implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

Comment: @NobeelGardenish - thanks, I'll take a look at it and get back to you

Comment: @NobeelGardenish - I see now that I misunderstood the problem. So the solution is: use getIntent() with TimeActivity and pass the int value into the (modified) constructor of CustomAdapter. (And never ever instantiate an Activity on your own, and also do not try to access variables of one Activity (MainActivity) directly from another one (TimeActivity) or its components (CustomAdapter) - this will only invite trouble)

Comment: For example your self-instantiated Activity will never be shown to the user. So they can't enter any values. So next one might think of having static variables ... and end up with an app which is hard to maintain even before it's released the first time

Comment: The problem has been solved by using the constructor of customAdapter.

Comment: @NobeelGardenish - thanks for letting me know -  and good luck with your project :D